# Declare a Member variable of both a class and interface in Java

Tags: java, generics, member

I have a class with a constructor that accepts one argument that must be of the class `Context` (or any subclass) *and* implement the interface `Alertable`. I will use this argument to set a member variable that will then be used throughout the class as either an instance of `Context` or an instance of `Alertable`.

```
public <T extends Context & Alertable> ApiGateway(T context)
{
     // Constructor code here
}
```

How can I declare a member variable `mAlertableContext` such that it is also both of class `Context` and implements interface `Alertable`?

I've tried sticking the generic definition in various places in the code, but they keep coming up as syntax errors. Ideally, I'd like to have a member variable like `<T> mAlertableContext` or something similar, where I can treat `mAlertableContext` as either a `Context` or an `Alertable`.

One (admittedly very bad) workaround I've come up with is to declare two member variables, one of type `Context` and the other `Alertable`, and assign them both the *same* constructor argument and use them as which ever class/interface object I need them to be in the class `ApiGateway`.

```
private Context mContext;
private Alertable mAlertable;

public <T extends Context & Alertable> ApiGateway(T context)
{
    mContext = context;
    mAlertable = context;
}
```

I'm really hoping there is a better way to do this as it's obviously a duplication of data.

Comment: If that last snippet works for you, then I don't really see why you need them to be the 1 type. That forces unneeded restrictions on the user of your class. I would also just use 2 separate constructor parameters. Don't worry about duplication of data, there pretty much is none (except for a 32 bit compressed OOP (pointer)), since these are both reference types.

Comment: Jorn may be right.  But if there's a good reason to require it to be the same object, I think you've found the best solution possible in Java.  I'd recommend also: (1) adding a comment by the private variables to let readers know that the objects are the same, and (2) declaring them `final` to make it impossible for one of them to be changed by another method.  Also, if `Context` and `Alertable` are your own classes (not in the runtime or 3rd-party library), consider defining an `AlertableContext` class.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tips! I guess I'll go ahead and comment my intention of using two member variables. I did think about creating a composite class, but the class `Context` is an abstract Android library class.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea to use one "mAlertableContext" member variable from the perspective of `ApiGateway`. In any case, you are required to define how to deal with an object that is an `Alertable` and a `Context`. In creating an "mAlertableContext" variable, you are specifically required to create a definition of the combination of an `Alertable` and a `Context` object.

I think the best approach is to follow ajb's comment suggestion and create an `AlertableContext` class for the `ApiGateway`. Abstract the details of how you combine an `Alertable` and a `Context` away from the `ApiGateway` and put these details into the `AlertableContext` - on a need-to-know basis, the `ApiGateway` doesn't need to know how you've defined the combination of `Alertable` and `Context`. Leave that definition to the `AlertableContext` class.

It makes sense to have an `Alertable` variable *and* a `Context` variable in the `AlertableContext` class because the `AlertableContext` itself defines that its object may be one or the other, so the two variables of `AlertableContext` serve as a map between methods and their implementations. The `Alertable` and `Context` variables are references to the same object, so there are not two objects taking up memory space. They're just mapping definitions.

```
public class ApiGateway {

    private AlertableContext mAlertableContext;

    public <T extends Context & Alertable> ApiGateway(T context) {
        // Constructor code here
        mAlertableContext = new AlertableContext(context);
    }

    public void doAnApiCall() {

        // now the Context and Alertable members are available from mAlertableContext
        mAlertableContext.alert();
        mAlertableContext.doAContextThing();
    }
}

class AlertableContext extends Context implements Alertable {

    private Context context;
    private Alertable alertable;

    <T extends Context & Alertable> AlertableContext(T alertableContext) {
        this.context = alertableContext;
        this.alertable = alertableContext;
    }

    // override Context methods
    @Override
    public void doAContextThing() {
        context.doAContextThing();
    }

    // required from Alertable
    public void alert() {
        alertable.alert();
    }
}
```

If you don't like the separate variables, I know of one more option -- casting. You can avoid separate `Alertable` and `Context` objects and have an `Object` type object. Personally I think this is a bit more confusing, but it should work.

```
class AlertableContext extends Context implements Alertable {

    private Object alertableContext;

    <T extends Context & Alertable> AlertableContext(T alertableContext) {
        this.alertableContext = alertableContext;
    }

    // override Context methods
    @Override
    public void doAContextThing() {
        ((Context) alertableContext).doAContextThing();
    }

    // required from Alertable
    public void alert() {
        ((Alertable) alertableContext).alert();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is begging to promote the `<T>` into a class type parameter:

1. You are asking to have a member field typed `<T>`.
2. You are passing this `<T>` in the constructor.

So it would look like:

```
// you can compile this snippet:

class Context {}
interface Alertable {};

class ApiGateWay<T extends Context & Alertable> {

   private final T myContext;

   ApiGateWay(T context) {
     myContext = context;
   }
}
```

Then you can instantiate `ApiGateWays` like so:

```
// you CANNOT compile this snippet:

class ContextX extends Context implements Alertable { ... }
...
ContextX ctx = ...;
...
ApiGateWay<ContextX> agwX = new ApiGateWay<>(ctx);
```